# EF Core 3.1 How to include nested property of a owned entity

Tags: asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, cqrs, ef-core-3.1

I have following relationships:

```
    public class Order : IAggregateRoot
    {
        public Guid OrderId { get; private set; }
        public string Title { get; private set; }
    
        private ICollection<OrderProduct> _orderProducts;
    
        private Order()
        {
            _orderProducts = new List<OrderProduct>();
        }
    }
    public class OrderProduct
    {
        public Guid OrderProductId { get; private set; }
        public int Quantity { get; private set; }
        public Order Order { get; private set; }
        public Product Product { get; private set; }
        public bool Purchased { get; private set; }

        private OrderProduct()
        {
        }
    }
    internal class OrderEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
    {
        private readonly string orderProducts = "_orderProducts";
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Orders");

            builder.HasKey(b => b.OrderId);

            builder.OwnsMany<OrderProduct>(orderProducts, x =>
            {
                x.ToTable("OrderProducts");
                x.HasKey(y => y.OrderProductId);
                x.WithOwner(y => y.Order);
                x.HasOne(x => x.Product)
                    .WithMany();
            });
        }
    }
```

Order is aggregate root, owns collection of OrderProduct entities. Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities owned types are included by default(without using the **Include** method).

My question is, how can I include Product for each OrderProduct when I load Order from db by following method:

```
public async Task<App.Domain.Orders.Order> GetOrder(Guid orderId)
{
    return await _appDbContext.Orders
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
}
```

Is it possible in such a configuration of types and without exposing the collection of OrderProduct from Order?

Comment: I can do something like follows: `return await _shoppingAppContext.Orders.Include("_orderProducts.Product")
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.OrderId == orderId);` but it seems to me that it is not the best approach.

Comment: As @j.arap saysm you just need the include, though you don't need it to be a string, you can actually just use `Orders.Include(x => x.Product) - which makes it more fluid like, and easier to refactor - btw note - using stings isbad practice. Otherwise you might as well write PHP where turtles are stings - all the way down.

Comment: Some other notes...

In your OrderProduct, replace OrderProductId with Id (that'll automatically identify it as the key - by default).  Use an explicit name like this is the old school way of doing things, which I don't hate, but you have to get used to the new ways).

Also the .ToTable(name) - is not needed  and a bit old school, the table will use the entity name, its not necessary to use .ToTable("name").

It's not always easy to reprogram your brain, but the new modern way is actually way better, and requires less config / code - when you get used to it.

Comment: Set this up right, and you can remove the whole `OrderEntityTypeConfiguration` class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can not do something like this `Orders.Include(x => x.Product)`, because Product is navigation property inside OrderProduct, not in Order entity.

Comment: OK. Well then you want `Orders.Include(x => x.OrderProduct).ThenInclude(y => y.Product)`. The `ThenInclude` goes from the last include, so y in this case is the OrderProduct.  I know, this doesn't fulfil your exact requirements of not exposing the OrderProduct - but that's the way it is.  If you don't want to expose the whole lot to other parts of your application, then have a class that turns the data object into a proper model.

Answer (score 2):

My goal was to avoid using hard-coded strings for eager load, solution which I found is as follows:

```
internal class OrderEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsMany<OrderProduct>(x => x.OrderProducts, x =>
            {
                x.WithOwner(y => y.Order);
                x.HasOne(x => x.Product)
                    .WithMany();

                x.OwnedEntityType.FindNavigation(nameof(OrderProduct.Product)).SetIsEagerLoaded(true);
            }
        );
        builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Order.OrderProducts))
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);            
    }
}
    
public class Order : IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }

    private List<OrderProduct> _orderProducts;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<OrderProduct> OrderProducts => _orderProducts.AsReadOnly();

    private Order()
    {
        _orderProducts = new List<OrderProduct>();
    }
}
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    public async Task<Order> GetOrder(Guid orderId)
    {
        return await _shoppingAppContext.Orders
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
    }
}
```

Thanks that Product is eager loaded by default. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can't get Product for each of the OrderProduct in the Order object is that you are making OrderProduct as an owned type of Order while Product is not an owned type of OrderProduct.

That's why you can get OrderProduct without .Include() method on Order object and can't get Product without .Include() method on OrderProduct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that I can use the Include and ThenInclude methods, but I would like to leave the OrderProduct collection private. In this case, I have to use a hard-coded string in the Include method - I don't think that's elegant solution.
Is there any other option to load nested property of owned type?